# Removing DC from multi DC cluster in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a two datacenter site (dc1 and dc2). I am writing with replication of 3 (dc1:3 , dc2:3) on dc1. dc2 is backup site taking no traffic. I upgraded all the nodes of dc2 to C* version 3.11.2. Nodes of dc1 are on C* version 2.1.16. Now due to some issue I have to rollback my upgrade. I have two options

1. Data backup restore the complete  site (dc1 and dc2) - It will cause a lot of data loss.
2. Remove dc2 from dc1 using steps given [here](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/02/26/data-center-switch.html#phase_3).

Is there any issue in removing a site(dc2) in case of mixed C* versions?

Comment: You didn't do snapshot before performing upgrade?

Comment: I took the snapshot and in point 1 (Data backup restore ) I am talking about that  only. But I do not want to revert to old state because 3 days have passed since I am in this mixed state. So to avoid data loss I am considering option 2 that I should remove the upgraded site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me, I would:

1. Take DC2 out of replication.
2. Shutdown nodes on DC2.
3. Remove the nodes/assassinate them.
4. Uninstall C* completely.
5. Wipe the nodes of all data/logs/configuration.
6. Install C* and reconfigure.
7. Add nodes to a new DC.

This means there's no data loss by having to restore from backups. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, second option is seems to be good and you can recover your data safely. You should remove DC2 datacenter from your existing cluster. As you are saying no traffic on DC2  so it could be easy to performing addition and removal operation.

You need to follow the steps as below.

1. Change the replication factor of keyspaces.
2. Stop the Cassandra services on DC2.
3. You can remove the nodes from existing cluster via nodetool removenode command if it is creating a issue you can use assassinate.
4. Once node removed from the cluster one by one you need to uninstall the Cassandra there.
5. Remove existing data on removed node completely.
6. Then, you need to install fresh Cassandra there based on previous configuration, you can refer config files from existing cluster or you took a backup for you config on 2.1.16
7. Now, you need to add your datacenter again on cluster.

In this way, you can easily get your datacenter and data quickly.

You can refer the documentation here for any confusion in addition
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsAddDCToClusterDesigDC.html